# How to change kendo multiselect placeholder?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, placeholder, multi-select

1. Why kendo multiselect placeholder so different instead of any other kendo elements?
2. If you go to http://dojo.telerik.com/oHuqe - you can see, that placeholder is red, but if you change element to Multiselect - it backs to default.
3. Also, for multiselect you need specify placeholder during initialization, not in html

So, question is - anybody knows how to change multiselect placeholder to default styles of other kendo elements?

Regards

Comment: It is because "placeholder" in multiselect widget is rendered as normal text. http://dojo.telerik.com/oHuqe/2

Comment: So, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

http://dojo.telerik.com/ApIdUlAV

```
$("#size").kendoMultiSelect({
  placeholder: "Select productasdasds..."
})
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Sure, so, in Kendo we have custom elements like this one 'kendoMultiselect' and it has props like 'placeholder', that it